# Eclipse (Java, testng Project): Multiple packages are being created

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

When I create a java project in eclipse it automatically creates a default package in the src file(which I do not intend to) and when I try to create a package for eg. com.utility.org it goes ahead and creates extra packages named com, com.utility, com.utility.org

[Snapshot of the error I am facing in creating packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jrtee.png)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this and the screenshot does not show an empty Java project after its creation. Maybe a plug-in you have installed does that (I can see a _TestNG_ view, which is something you have installed into Eclipse).

Comment: What Eclipse version are you using? I can´t reproduce this on Eclipse Mars. Is this a new installation?

Comment: @AlexanderHeim Eclipse Mars is a couple of years old and many releases behind. → https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide `(default package)` by checking the *Empty parent packages* filter (Package Explorer's kebab menu > Filters...).

In Java, packages match the directory architecture of the source folder, so creating a `com.utility.org` package will create the `com/utility/org` nested folders. Hence `com` and `com.utility` are not "extra" packages but actual packages corresponding to the `com/` and `com/utility` folders. `(default package)` corresponds to the source folder itself.

Since empty, `com` and `com.utility` should be hidden by the filter. Alternatively you can also ask the Explorer to group nested packages as a tree (Package Explorer's kebab menu > Package Presentation > Hierarchical):

[image]